# ERROR 1200 (HY000): The server is not configured as slave; fix in config file or with CHANGE MASTER TO

Tags: mysql

my.cnf part is

```
   [mysqld_safe]
   log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
   pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
   log_error = /var/log/mysql_error.log

    server-id = 3;
    log-bin = mysql-bin
    relay-log = prod-relay-bin
    slave-skip-errors =
```

And when I am restarting slave giving error

> ERROR 1200 (HY000): The server is not configured as slave; fix in
>   config file or with CHANGE MASTER TO

Then I checked server id:

`mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';`

```
    +---------------+-------+
    | Variable_name | Value |
    +---------------+-------+
    | server_id     | 0     |
    +---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

`server_id` can't be set to `0` for mysql replication to work.